# Getting WiFI to outbuilding using ethernet

Tags: ethernet, wireless-networking

I have an internet provider in my main house (Century Link).  This provider installed a new router and modem. I have a new auxiliary dwelling on my property and the electrician installed an ethernet connection from my existing modem to the outbuilding.  Using information from the internet I connected the existing modem to the ethernet plug that runs to the new building.  I have installed my old router (previous internet provider) in the out building.  I can use the out-buildings router address (192.168.1.1) and see and connect to the router on my computer (including logging in with an administrator account).    My problem is that I do not get an internet connect through this router.

I am trying to determine why I do not get an internet connection with this setup.  I do not know whether my old router is incompatible with the new modem/internet provider or if I just have a wiring issue.  Any help is appreciated.
Here is the modem.
[image]
Here is the Century Link router
[image]
Here is my old router that I want to use in the outbuilding (Netgear 80)
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while setting up your home network is DIY, that's not the kind of DIY we cover here. I'd suggest SuperUser

Comment: Your original Netgear router has probably 4 Ethernet ports together, and then, 1 separate port for something else intended to go to "the world" side.  Is that "something else" a DSL (possibly 6-pin RJ11, similar but narrower than 8-pin ethernet cables which won't fit), or coaxial like for cable, or is it another Ethernet?

Comment: This is a networking question, not home improvement. However; are you looking to have wireless networking or wired? If wireless, set up a mesh network. It's a simple problem to solve, but this is not quite the right place for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want to set up the Router to Router connection, use method 1 in this link [Router to Router Setup](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-one-router-to-another-to-expand-the-network/)

Note that the connecting cables must be in the proper ports, and the old router must be configured to extend the network.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer66. method 1 at your link was exactly the fix.  I connected the primary router ethernet out to the secondary router LAN in via ethernet.  Connected.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to networking.

What you need in the outbuilding is a **hub**, or an improved hub called a **switch**, and a switch can include a **WiFi Gateway** (which simply adds the WiFi transport layer to the existing network).

The problem is, you are using none of those things, you are using a **router** which is designed to *establish* local networks, not extend them.

Now, the old router certainly contains all the necessary *hardware bits* to do what you want.  However, it will need to be configured to do that, and by your stated skill level I'm guessing you're not there yet.  For that matter the software provided in the router may not stretch that far.

But that's what I would do.  Re-configure the router so it acts as a switch and a WiFi bridge, i.e. it is an invisible part of the same subnet (192.168.0.0/24 probably), it doesn't mess with the IP level of the stack, and simply forwards packets to the new router.  The new router is the one assigning IP addresses in the subnet.

This will also give better latency and less complications... since you won't be doing NAT on top of NAT.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally expert on networking, but I think your modems are conflicting with each other. You only need one modem and that's connected to the DSL from clink. If it's a true Ethernet cable (cat-5 or cat-6) all you need is a simple, unmanaged switch in your outbuilding connected to the modem in your house. Even an 8 port unmanaged switch is only about $20. They are super simple. Plug and Play. No settings. Just  dumb switches that do one thing well:  Share an ethernet cable with multiple devices.

You could fiddle with your old modem forever, changing DHCP settings, address ranges, and other arcane settings trying to get it work.

Comment: By connecting your old router to the new router, you created a sub-domain.  (different set of IP-address).  @George Anderson, is correct, the easiest thing to do is replace your old router with a switch (which just extends the new router  IP address to the ADU.

Comment: @Programmer66  Thanks for a more detailed answer, but did you mean "router" or "modem"...maybe router built into modem, common these days.   And thanks for confirming my answer!

Comment: Thanks, for the answers.  I guess what I want is to provide wireless connection to the devices in the outbuilding and not hard-wired ethernet connections.

Comment: I see that I mixed up router and modem in my answer and edited it to use the correct terminologies.

Comment: See my answer for connecting the two routers (new router connected to the modem, with a ethernet cable connecting to the the WAN port on the old router.

Comment: @GBG  That's not hard to do.   Get a WIFI router, plug the cable from the house into the WIFI router and after some configuration you have WIFI!   They all need a hardwired ethernet connection to get signal. think about it...how else would a WIFI router connect to the internet? (see additional comment below).  I have both hardwired and WIFI in my house and it's fine. WIFI is nice for guest access, but I prefer hardwired. It's more secure, faster, more reliable.

Comment: @GBG OK, one more comment. There is a way for a WIFI router to get signal without a hard wired connection if there is another WIFI router within range. It's called "bridge mode".  I helped install (didn't do it myself, I need smarter people than me to do it), but "supervised". In my church we needed to get internet access to a certain point in the sanctuary. It's a historic building and cabling would have been very difficult.  So we set up 2 routers in bridge mode.  Works great, even supporting a facebook live feed with no issues.